# How to navigate the user from the login page to the home page if the HTTP response code is 200 in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I want to redirect the user from the login page to the home page when the HTTP status code is 200. (I do not have token) I don't know how to set the isLoggedIn to true when the HTTP status is 200 and to false when it is 401. I think I need to do it in the auth.service.ts.

Here is what I've got for the moment:

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn">
  <app-home></app-home>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!authService.isLoggedIn">
  <app-login></app-login>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './login/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {User} from '../user';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {RestResponse} from '../rest-response';

const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(
  {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  isLoggedIn = false;

  private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8085/api/login';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(credentials: User): Observable<HttpResponse<RestResponse>> {
    return this.http.post<RestResponse>(this.loginUrl, credentials, {headers: httpHeaders, observe: 'response'}).subscribe(
      (res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    } else {
      this.isLoggedIn = false;}
      });
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {User} from '../user';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent {

  isLoading: false ;
  error: string = null;

  loginFormGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({  usernameFormControl : new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ])
    , passwordFormControl : new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ])});

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

onSubmit(form: FormGroup){
     console.log(form.value);
     this.isLoading = true;
     this.authService.login(new User(this.loginFormGroup.get('usernameFormControl').value, this.loginFormGroup.get('passwordFormControl').value)).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      },
       errorMessage => {
         console.log(errorMessage);
         this.error = 'Sorry, your username and password are incorrect.';
         this.isLoading = false;
       }
     );
     form.reset();
}
```

rest-response.ts

```
export class RestResponse {
  code: number;
  status: string;
  message: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in auth.service.ts

```
login(credentials: User): Observable<HttpResponse<RestResponse>> {
    return this.http.post<RestResponse>(this.loginUrl, credentials, {headers: httpHeaders, observe: 'response'}).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      }, err => {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working. I get the following error: ERROR TypeError: this.authService.login(...).subscribe is not a function. When I hover over it in the text editor it says: TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<HttpResponse<RestResponse>>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Answer (score 0):

Use JWT tokens for authorization purposes. It is very handy.

If you dont want to use tokens, what can you do is 
On successful login, write any varibale in local storage and when logout function is called, delete the variable in local storage.

But i would prefer jwt tokens. If you want to know how to implement tokens, please refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toRmWFzB6-E&t=323s)